# Modify WordPress WooCommerce Breadcrumbs

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, breadcrumbs

How do I removed the product title or page title from the breadcrumbs?

I just want the lead-up like below

Home - Category - Subcategory

But nothing after that...

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can do so by creating a child theme and override the breadcrumb template.

https://gist.github.com/dwiash/4064836

> But if you're going to change its whole inner HTML structure, you'll
>   need to override the template function. To do so, you need to copy the
>   /woocommerce/templates/shop/breadcrumb.php file to
>   /woocommerce/shop/breadcrumb.php in your theme directory